# How can I translate months in DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

In this plot example, I get the months in English abbreviation:

```
DateListPlot[{#, RandomReal[]}&/@DateRange[{2020,1,1}, {2021,01,31}, "Month"]]
```

[image]
How can I translate the abbreviated names using this rule:

```
monthNameRule = <|"Jan"-> "Jan", "Feb"-> "Fev", "Mar"-> "Mar", "Apr"-> "Abr", "May"-> "Mai", "Jun"-> "Jun", "Jul"-> "Jul", "Ago"-> "Ago", "Sep"-> "Set", "Oct"-> "Out", "Nov"-> "Nov", "Dec"-> "Dez"|>
```

Maybe there is some Global Variable with Month names? Any Clue?

I'm know I can use `Ticks` to specify manually, but I would like to use Mathematica automatic magic for ticker position, and just translate the result.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** A generalization to translate months and days:

```
ClearAll[translateDates, translatedDateTicks]
translateDates[f_: (Capitalize[StringTake[#, 3]] &)] := StringReplace[
  CanonicalName[#] | Capitalize[StringTake[CanonicalName[#], 3]] -> f[#2] & @@@ 
    Join @@ LanguageData[#, {"MonthNames", "Days"}]] &;

translatedDateTicks[f_: (Capitalize[StringTake[#, 3]] &)][l_String, 
  n_: All, ds_: "MonthName"] :=  Replace[System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, n, ds], 
    s_String :> translateDates[f][l]@s, All] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = {#, RandomReal[]} & /@ DateRange[{2020, 1, 1}, {2020, 02, 15}, "Day"];

DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> 800, LabelStyle -> 12, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All},
  {translatedDateTicks[]["Portuguese", 30, "DayName"], 
   translatedDateTicks[]["Spanish", 30, 
     {"DayName", "\n", "MonthName", "\n", "YearShort"}]}}]
```

[image]

```
data2 = {#, RandomReal[]} & /@ DateRange[{2020, 1, 1}, {2021, 01, 31}, "Month"];

DateListPlot[data2, ImageSize -> 800, LabelStyle -> 12, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, 
  {translatedDateTicks[Identity]["Chinese", 15, "MonthName"], 
   translatedDateTicks[Identity]["Russian", 10, {"MonthName", " / ", "YearShort"}]}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[monthShort, dTicks]
monthShort[lang_] := CanonicalName[#] -> Capitalize[StringTake[#2, 3]] & @@@ 
  LanguageData[lang, "MonthNames"]

dTicks[l_String, n_:All] := System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, n, "MonthName"] /. 
   monthShort[l] &;

dTicks[a_Association, n_: All] := System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, n, 
   "MonthNameShort"] /. a &;
```

***Example:***

```
monthNameRule = <|"Jan" -> "Jan", "Feb" -> "Fev", "Mar" -> "Mar", 
   "Apr" -> "Abr", "May" -> "Mai", "Jun" -> "Jun", "Jul" -> "Jul", 
   "Aug" -> "Ago", "Sep" -> "Set", "Oct" -> "Out", "Nov" -> "Nov", "Dec" -> "Dez"|>;

DateListPlot[{#, RandomReal[]} & /@ DateRange[{2020, 1, 1}, {2021, 01, 31}, "Month"], 
 ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 16,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {dTicks[monthNameRule, 10], dTicks["Portuguese"]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'll wait 24h before accept. Tks a lot.

Comment: what version are you using? If I copy and past your answer in V12.1, I get error, and no translation.

Comment: I am using version 11.3 (windows 10 -64b)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer:

```
DateListPlot[{#, RandomReal[]} & /@ 
  DateRange[{2020, 1, 1}, {2021, 01, 31}, "Month"], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Table[{{2020, Month[[1]], 1}, 
      Month[[2]]}, {Month, {Range[12], {"Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", 
         "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", 
         "Dez"}}\[Transpose]}], None}}]
```

But this is done by manual setting, which may not meet your requirements. I would also like to know how to automatically convert the date format to Portuguese and other language formats.